# vb.net code is not running on asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I wanted to make a simple asp.net example page with just shows "Hello, World!" and current time.

but it shows only "Hello, world!", not time. This is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>
   This is a test
  </title>
  <script language="VB" runat="server">
   Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblMessage.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
   End Sub
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p> Hello, World! </p>
  <asp Labelid="lblMessage" runat="server" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Why does this happen and what's cure for it?

Comment: What type of file is this (what is its extension)? Plain .html or .aspx (it should be the latter)?

Comment: Check 2: in your browser, do a "view source". You shouldn't see the "runat=server" parts

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably the malformation of the label.

Not sure why you're using a label here in the first place (typically they're used for labeling form inputs)

```
<asp Labelid="lblMessage" runat="server" />
```

Should be

```
<asp:Label id="lblMessage" runat="server" />
```